# Can't add variable to table, that starts with underscore (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I can't add value to MySQL, because rows name starts with _

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field '_user_id' doesn't have a
>   default value

I can't change SQL table preferences, because we are writing new project with old DB.

```
     $attributes = request()->validate([
        'cert_id' => 'required',
        'issuer_country' => 'required',
        'is_flag' => '',
        'is_unlimited' => '',
        'issuer' => '',
        'from_date' => 'required',
        'to_date' => 'required',
        'licence_number' => 'required',
     ]);

     $attributes['_user_id'] = 1;

     SeamanCert::create($attributes);

     class SeamanCert extends Model
     {
         protected $guarded = [];
         public $timestamps = false;
     }
```

Comment: Is `_user_id` in the `$fillable` attributes in your `SeamanCert` model?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it does, but it doesn't... I have protected $guarded = [];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Eloquent rejects columns starting with an underscore.
try this:
`DB::table('table_name')->insert($attributes);`

Comment: "_It is because Eloquent rejects columns starting with an underscore._" Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: No, but you can try it. for example, if you define two custom attributes `user_id` and `_user_id`, then you can't access them separately and you only can define `getUserId()` method for both, and it causes conflicts and errors. because Eloquent rejects underscore for this situation. @kerbholz

Answer (score 0):

There is a convention for Laravel naming [link](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions).

As [Motia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510517/5002040) says, Naming conventions helps you to avoid bugs.

If you cannot change your Database table, you should consider to use  [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) instead Eloquent.